# Twitter Bootstrap Creating a normal footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used the sticky footer in Bootstrap .. An example of which is

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site built by this</p>
            <a class="navar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on Youtube</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

But I want to use the normal footer.. So that I can only see that when I scroll to the bottom and not always.. How can I do that with the existing code in Bootstrap?

Thanks

Comment: try changing `navbar-fixed-bottom` to `navbar-static-bottom`

Comment: if you remove the `navbar-fixed-bottom` class and have that code at the end of the page, does not work?

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes yeah it's working.. but it's not full width.. How to get the full width footer?

Comment: try adding colm-12 class

Answer (score 0):

Use `navbar-static-bottom` and a `container-fluid` inside like this..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site built by this</p>
    <a class="navar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on Youtube</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/sa1xW9fyTW

Comment: Footer loses its position and takes body's height when tried your example